# change image in push notification popup

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I have developed the push notification functionality in my MobileFirst 7.1 app. Push notifications are working fine and I am able to receive them in my application. I want to change the image in the notification popup which is coming default as worklight image. See below screenshot. How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Android project's "res/drawable*" folders  ,you should find "push.png" file that shows this icon. If you change it to your own icon, make sure you maintain the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Realizing that you have already accepted an answer, I'll leave this here just in case someone else has the same problem.

I found that I had to run `cordova clean` before my build in order for the images to get copied into the .apk properly by the build process.